# How can I use FirestorePagingAdapter and options in my project?

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I am trying to begin with `FirestorePagingAdapter`  and `FirestorePagingOptions`
and I read the documentation carefully like here

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore

and applied it by step by step

1-
`implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.x.x'`

2- `Query baseQuery = mItemsCollection.orderBy("value", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);`

But when I am trying to add `FirestorePagingOptions`it appears by the **red line code** that means it is not imported or implemented well and I am not using any android architecture models. After a lot of searches, I found nothing clear about it 
So what is the right way to begin with `FirestorePagingAdapter`  ? what I should implement to begin with? 
this is my implementation

```
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    //google sign inj
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    //FIREBASE UI LIBRARY
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'

    implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.core:common:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it's too late to answer. I reached to this page as I faced exactly the same issue.
Adding `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.3.2'` to the gradle dependencies solved this issue.